# Как можно отправлять данные с android приложения в форму на web-сайте?

Tags: java, android

Всем доброго времени суток.

Допустим, что есть web-сайт, например, на котором можно оставить комментарий без регистрации.
Есть приложение под android, которое содержит в себе два элемента: lineEdit и простая кнопка.
Требуется по нажатию на кнопку в android приложении содержимое lineEdit отправить на web-сайт, т.е. оставить комментарий на web-сайте. 
Таким образом, подразумевается, что текст из lineEdit вставится в окно комментария на web-сайте, а затем программно нажимается кнопка на web-сайте, которая отправит комментарий.

Собственно, ключевым моментом является вопрос, как через android вставить текст именно в необходимую форму на web-сайте, а также как нажать необходимую кнопку на web-сайте. Как я понял, можно такое сделать через selenium. Действительно ли это так? Или, может быть, есть способы попроще?

Например, в C# нажать на кнопку было не очень сложно:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id").InvokeMember("click");
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Скорее всего, если вы посмотрите черех консоль браузера параметры запроса, отправляемого при нажатии на кнопку сайта (адрес, заголовки, тип)  и эмулируете этот запрос на андроиде, то коммент будет отправлен

Comment: Зачем эмулировать нажатие если можно передать данные скрипту на сервер? В том же виде POST/GET